# open camera in webview application using javascript and html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to open only camera, not any upload document selector .

I'm trying this code now:

```
<input type="file" class="ignore custom-file-input"  name="selfiPhoto" id="customFile" accept="image/*" capture="user">
```

It's working on chrome and other mobile browser but not in my application.
How can open only camera?

Comment: i think the approach would be quite different based on what operating system you are targeting. are you using phonegap or smthg like this? We need more Information

Comment: Please provide enough of your code so we can have a look: [reprex]

Comment: What is your application?